# ASP.NET Core MVC POST Method Not Being Called When Trying to Delete an Item

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, http-status-code-405

Hello StackOverflow community!

I'm encountering an issue in my ASP.NET Core MVC project where the POST method is not being called when trying to delete an item. Here's my code:

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(Guid id)
{
    var subcategory = await _uow.SubcategoryRepository.GetByGuidSubcategoryAsync(id);
    if (subcategory == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return View(subcategory);
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(Guid id)
{
    var subcategory = await _uow.SubcategoryRepository.GetByGuidSubcategoryAsync(id);
    if (subcategory == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    await _uow.SubcategoryRepository.DeleteAsync(subcategory);
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

View:

```
@model APP_LAWYER.DAL.Entities.Subcategory

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete Subcategory";
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<h2>Delete Subcategory</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<div>
    <h4>@Model.Name</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            Description
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Model.Description
        </dd>
        <!-- Add more fields as necessary -->
    </dl>

    <form asp-action="DeleteConfirmed" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" method="post">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" /> |
        <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
    </form>
</div>
```

When I try to delete an item, I'm getting a 405 error. Upon debugging, I found that the POST `DeleteConfirmed` method is not being called. I've checked and confirmed that `@Model.Id` contains the correct ID of the item I want to delete.

Can anyone help me understand why the POST method is not being called and how I can fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

I have tried debugging the application and found that the POST method `DeleteConfirmed` is not being called when I try to delete an item. I have also checked that the `@Model.Id` in the form contains the correct ID of the item I want to delete. I was expecting the `DeleteConfirmed` method to be called, and the item with the corresponding ID to be deleted from the database. However, I'm getting a 405 error instead. I am not sure why this is happening and need help understanding and fixing this issue.

Comment: I would open the browser developer tools screen's network tab and observe what is going over the network. Is the request really a post request? Or is the Id parameter in place or not? And this should fix your problem: `[HttpPost("id")]`. If you don't state it is especially in the rout it will be treated as a query string. So your HTML form posts sth like this : `DeleteConfirmed/212313` but your backend expect sth like this : `DeleteConfirmed?id=123123`

Comment: Yeah. It's almost always a good idea to specify where parameters come from using `[FromQuery]`, `[FromRoute]`, `[FromBody]`, `[FromHeader]`, `[FromForm]`

Comment: Does adding `[FromBody]` or `[FromForm]` (this is likely correct) helps? `public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed([FromBody] Guid id)`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#sources